# Setting up vim under Win 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, vim

I try to setup vim, which is quite difficult for me.

Personally I prefer to run programs via the cmd.

So I set the home path of my vim 7.4 via advance settings,

so that I can use the command `gvim.exe` in the cmd.

But I would prefer to use a shorter command to run the `gvim.exe`.

How can I make such a shortcut?

Instead of typing `gvim.exe` I would prefer typing `vim` or `gvim`.

best greetings

Tim

Comment: It's unclear from your question, but has your setup put the `gvim` directory in your `PATH`? If so you can just type `gvim` in a `cmd` shell (in the same way you can type `notepad` instead of `notepad.exe`. If its not in the `PATH` then add it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, you can rename it to whatever you want so you don't have to type out `gvim.exe`. You could call it `v.exe` if you really wanted, as long as nothing clashes with it. The .exe is entirely optional as well. So you could just call `v file.txt`.

Then you can place it on your machine somewhere and add it's path to the environmental variable PATH, meaning it can be run from anywhere on your machine (You can also place it somewhere that already is in PATH, but it's a lot neater to give it it's own location, say `C:\Tools\GVIM\`).

To add to the PATH variable: ([guide here](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-can-i-add-new-folder-my-system-path) for general use, the interface is actually a lot nicer in Windows 10):

1. Go to `Control Panel` -> `System`
2. Click `Advanced system settings`
3. Click the `Environment Variables` button.
4. Under `System Variables`, select `Path`, then click `Edit`. (You can choose if you want it for just your User, the list at the top, or the whole machine, the list at the bottom)

[image]

5. Click `New` and add your folder path (`C:\Tools\GVIM\`)
6. Click `OK` to all screens, you can now use your command from any folder in CMD.

Comment: So if i rename the gvim.exe it will make no issues, right?

Comment: @TimSobkowiak Unless there are other programs/utilities reliant on it being named correctly, it should be fine. If it's not, just rename it back.

Comment: for the env variables it is a lot easier just to go into search and type env it is usually the first option

Answer (score 0):

Just install cygwin from cygwin.org!  It handles all your unix utilities as exe files and gvim is included.  After installing, go to a cygwin shell and cd /cygdrive/c to get to the root of your C:\ drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an alias to your Powershell profile as follows
`New-Alias -Name vim -Value 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim90\vim.exe'`

You are as already mentioned free to call the alias whatever you want.
From here you can launch vim from Powershell.